# Dynamically Add Multiple Jquery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Let's say I have a for loop dynamically generating Jquery functions - like so:

```
 function addJqueryFunctions(divListJSON) {
    for(var i in divListJSON)
    {
        var id = divListJSON[i].id;

        $('#' + id + ').magicfunction();
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that the Jquery functions generated in the for loop make it to the page and are run?

Comment: You're not generating functions, you're just calling the same function repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an element by ID, you need to prefix it with `#`

```
$('#' + id).magicFunction();
```

Notice that the variable and `+` operator have to be *outside* the quotes.

Comment: Left the prefix out in the original post, but will functions work if generated in a loop? I.e. $('#id').draggable

Comment: You're not "generating" anything, you're just calling a function. And each time, you're calling it with a different context parameter.

Comment: Your modified question has an extra quote before `)`. If you have that in your actual code it will report a syntax error.

Comment: There are some issues with generating closures in `for` loops. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue. But you don't have anything like that in your question.